# CTE Hierarchy Question - 1 table, 2 columns

Tags: sql, ssms, common-table-expression

I'm new to CTEs, and I am slowly starting to understand the basics.

I have a table that essentially goes in this pattern:

| CUSTOMER X | CUSTOMER Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |

I was wondering if a CTE would help return the numbers 1 through 6 (CUSTOMER Y) if Number 1 in CUSTOMER X had a specific column flagged for relevancy.

Customer 1 would be considered the main customer, while 2 - 6 could be stores related to said customer.

My end goal would be propogating down this relevancy flag for customers 2 - 6 if customer 1 has it and I'm currently trying to figure out how to get that full list.

I'd want the CTE to return a distinct list of customers.

| CUSTOMER |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Comment: Could you post the output you're trying to achieve (as a table)?

Comment: Yes, a recursive CTE could help to return all related customers, have you tried? Beware of circular references like 1-2-3-2...

Comment: Hierarchy lookups are the specific scenario that Recursive CTEs were designed to solve. So yes, conceptually CTEs will help by their very definition. Our question to you is what you want this to look like. Ideally you should include more information and an example output, otherwise this question will end up being closed https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server